# jQuery ui - define .ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text for radio button only

Tags: jquery-ui

We can define the padding of button by changing the css of `.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text`, like this:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    padding: .3em .8em .3em;
}
```

But my challenge is, I would like to change ONLY the `.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text` for radio button, not for other types of buttons.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text[type="radio"] { /* CSS properties here */ }
```

More details @ http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

**Edit**
If you must have it working in IE6 as suggested below, you can use jQuery to apply the styles:

```
$('.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text[type="radio"]').css('padding', '.3em .8em .3em');
```

Comment: Note: It's not supported in IE6.

Comment: I totally agree, but it's not dead yet and some people (myself included) are forced to work with it. :(

Comment: I'm actually sad to hear that, I stopped supporting it summer-autumn last year. Show your employer the ie6countdown link :)

Comment: I tried the above method in jquery ui downloaded demo page for radio button but it didn't work. What I did is in the demo page, I simply add  
<style>
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text { padding: .3em .8em .3em;}
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text[type="radio"] { padding: .1em .5em .1em;}
</style>
before <head>

The radio buttons are using .3em .8em .3em as padding, not .1em .5em .1em

What have I done wrong?